# VBA to loop round worksheets by index number

Tags: vba, excel

How do I change a cell in particular sheets using the worksheet index number

For example:

```
Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "Hello"
```

I want to do this for worksheets from 1 to 12

Comment: You can use a variable and a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple for loop:

```
For i = 1 To 12
    Worksheets(i).Range("A1").Value = "Hello"
Next
```

Although you may want to check that the sheets exist first...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without a loop ! :

```
Sub ALLpoi()
    Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Value = "Hello"
End Sub
```

This is one case in which using `Selection` is good.  In this case `Selection` can span cells on different worksheets *(unlike a range)*

Answer (score 1):

There are two options (from my expirience) to do what you asking for:

**1) using loop (several variants)**

```
Sub test1()
    Dim i%
    For i = 1 To 12
        Worksheets(i).[A1].Value2 = "Hello"
    Next
End sub
```

or

```
Sub test2()
    Dim i%: i = 1
    While i < 13
         Worksheets(i).[A1].Value2 = "Hello": i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub test3()
    Dim i%: i = 1
    Do While i < 13
        Worksheets(i).[A1].Value2 = "Hello": i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub test4()
    Dim i%: i = 1
    Do Until i = 13
        Worksheets(i).[A1].Value2 = "Hello": i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub test5()
    Dim i%: i = 1
    Do
        Worksheets(i).[A1].Value2 = "Hello": i = i + 1
    Loop Until i = 13
End Sub
```

**2) without loop**

```
Sub test()
    Worksheets(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)).Select
    [A1].Activate: ActiveCell.Value2 = "Hello"
End Sub
```